# Compare an array element to particular string of characters in javascript

Tags: javascript, compare

I have an array of characters like :

```
var invalid_chars = ['<', '>', '$', '@', '&', '+', '(', ')', '[', ']', '{', '}',' ','`'];
```

and have a string like :

```
var id_val = $("#id_number").val(); //text field contains "mu 1$2@345"
```

So I want to **restrict** the **invalid_chars** to be entered in the filed.

For that I have the following code:

```
var id_val = $("#id_number").val();
var invalid_chars = ['<', '>', '$', '@', '&', '+', '(', ')', '[', ']', '{', '}',' ','`'];
if (in_array(invalid_chars,id_val)) {
  console.info("HI");
}
```

But it shows me error."ReferenceError: in_array is not defined"

Please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`in_array()` is a PHP method. In JavaScript use [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Answer (score 1):

You need to write `in_array` function, simple example:

```
function in_array( arr, val ) {
    for( var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if( arr[ i ] == val ) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

or using regular expressions:

```
if( id_val.search( /[^0-9]/g ) == -1 )
```

or using regex you can strip all non-numeric characters:

```
var id_val = $("#id_number").val(); //text field contains "mu 1$2@345"
id_val = id_val.replace( /[^0-9]/g, '' );
console.log( id_val ); //text now field contains "12345"
```

or if you want wo allow latin char's as well:

`[^0-9A-Za-z]`

^ this will not include space char as well.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're using jQuery already, which has an [$.inArray()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.inArray/) utility method.

Answer (score 1):

You should turn your list of characters into a regular expression, in my opinion:

```
var badchars = /[<>$@&+()[\]{},` ]/;
if (badchars.test(id_val)) {
  // contains invalid characters
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexOf` on arrays, but older versions of MSIE's jScript engine don't support this method natively. So either augment the `Array.prototype` for those browsers (not without risks, obviously), or simply use a string of chars you want to test for:

```
var nonoChars = '<>$@&+()[]{},`';
for(var i = 0; i< id_val.length; i++)
{
    if (nonoChars.indexOf(id_val.charAt(i)) > -1)
    {
        alert('Char #' + (i + 1) + ' is not allowed!');
        return false;
    }
}
//input ok
```

But, in this case, a regex simply makes more sense:

```
if (id_val.match(/[<>$@&+()\[\]{},`]/))
{
    alert('Invalid input');
    return false;
}
//input ok
```